# Pydev Not Recognized in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, pydev

I've been using PyDev within Eclipse on my Mac for about two years now. Updated Eclipse today, and suddenly PyDev is completely missing. Tried everything, included a complete uninstall and fresh install, but although PyDev shows up as installed in the menu, it appears nowhere else.

PyDev version: 3.0.0.201311051910
Eclipse: Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819

I can't open a PyDev perspective, I can't create a new Python file, and I can't open an existing Python file without it just being seen as plain text.

I've got a huge assignment due tonight, help appreciated.

Comment: How did you update eclipse? Did you download a new version of eclipse or update it using the menu?

Comment: On the mac, I am using Eclipse Kepler and pydev from pydev - http://pydev.org/updates. Did you install it from therE? I'm on PyDev 2.8.2. Let me try upgrading to 3...

Comment: http://aptana.com/ has pydev built in, I'd give it a try

Comment: not sure if the OP is doing webwork.. Aptana does not have all the features of eclipse as it is geared towards webdev.

Comment: You can also check LiClipse for an Eclipse distribution which has the latest PyDev version pre-configured (and a VM).

Comment: BTW, the current issue seems to be that you don't have a java 7 vm to run PyDev on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PyDev installation problems with Kepler and Mac OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838294/pydev-installation-problems-with-kepler-and-mac-os)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To see what the problem is, I upgraded from PyDev 2.8.2 to 3.0.0 just for this. It caused me a world of hurt. That version is *filled* with bugs. Nothing is working for me, including the perspectives or the debugger. I just went back to 2.8.2 and all is well again. I am also on Kepler and Mac. Go to 2.8.2. YOu can uninstall pydev using eclipse, then simply install pydev using the easy zip file instructions here: http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html.

3.0.0 was just released yesterday. They obviously have some fixing to do!

Comment: Looks like it's back! I'm glad it wasn't just me. Not sure how they let a bug so massive slip by on the upgrade...

Comment: Well, the main thing currently isn't on PyDev, but not having Java 7  configured on target machines -- it's a bit unfortunate that Eclipse simply doesn't show PyDev instead of saying that a Java 7 VM is required in order to run it -- but the workaround shouldn't be downgrading to 2.8.x to get support to running on an older vm, but installing java 7 -- which was released back in 2011 -- and with the current range of exploits, it's probably even dangerous having such an old JVM running on your computer :)

Comment: This is not the issue. I am using Java 7 v 45, and I had the same problems as the OP with 3.0.0. OP installed a major version the day after it came out, so not surprising at all it didn't work. Along those same lines, this is why I am not on OSX10.9 yet!

Answer (score 11):

If you can't / will not upgrade to Java 7:

Uninstall latest PyDev version
 1. Help >> About Eclipse
 2. Press button "Installation Details"
 3. Select "PyDev for Eclipse"
 4. Press button "Uninstall..."
 5. Close, OK

Install version 2.8.2
 1. Help >> Install New Software...
 2. select in drop-down list "Work with:" PyDev Update Site - http://pydev.org/updates/
 3. De-select option "Show only the latest versions of available software"
 4. Select "PyDev for Eclipse, version 2.8.2"
 5. Press button "Next>"
 6. ...
 n. Restart Eclipse (as proposed)

Answer (score 10):

Check if you are using Java 7, it is needed now for PyDev 3.
Source: http://pydev.org/download.html and PyDev bugtracker.
After upgrading my java-version it worked for me again.

Comment: I am using Java 7 v 45.

Comment: Tommy, did you check if your eclipse is really using Java 7? I'm using ZendStudio, which brings its own java version with it. Zend 10 was using java 6, alas I installed java 7 on my machine. I've upgraded to Zend 10.5 which uses java 7 and everything worked again for me.

Answer (score 2):

The following solved the problem for me, on OS X Mavericks 10.9.2 initially with Java 1.7.0_55 (from Oracle, the standard Mavericks install I think, fully up to date)

- check the available Java virtual machines using the terminal :

> /usr/libexec/java_home -V

I initially only had Java 1.6 listed here (a similar check from within Eclipse also confirmed that **it was running 1.6, not the available 1.7** !)

- following posts suggesting that I had the Java 7 JRE but not the JDK, **I installed the JDK** from Oracle :
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html
- then checked again /usr/libexec/java_home -V
  ... and hurrah! 1.7 showing up !
- Restarted Eclipse... didn't change anything else : the previously installed PyDev started to work (just had to re-open files in the editor)

Answer (score 1):

It seems a lot of PyDev/Eclipse issues are a matter of using the correct Java JRE/JDK and PyDev for the version of Eclipse you're running.

From http://www.pydev.org/

Release 5.2.0

Important PyDev now requires Java 8 and Eclipse 4.5 onwards.

PyDev 4.5.5 is the last release supporting Java 7 and Eclipse 3.8. See: update sites page (http://www.pydev.org/update_sites/index.html) for the update site of older versions of PyDev.

Answer (score 1):

At start i was also facing same error that : The solution is not provide while installing PyDev - Python IDE for Eclipse 6.3.2 
and when I am When trying to install I receive the following message: Unable to read repository at https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/latest/content.xml. ?

Then i came up with the final solution :

follow the steps :

**Online Install**

The URL for installation of the feature is http://pydev.org/updates. You can use that URL to Install New Software... from the Help menu if the Eclipse Marketplace is not doing what you want.

and uncheck all the options mentioned below on Install New Software Window like:
Uncheck :

```
1.Show only the latest versions of available software
2.Group Items by category
3.Show only software applicable to target environment
4.Contact all update sites during install to find required software
```

**Offline Install**

If you meet the requirements (below) and continue to have problems with the update site, you can download to install offline. Get it from SourceForge (or follow the link from PyDev's website to SourceForge).

and uncheck all the options mentioned below on Install New Software Window like:
Uncheck :

```
1.Show only the latest versions of available software
2.Group Items by category
3.Show only software applicable to target environment
4.Contact all update sites during install to find required software
```

Answer (score 0):

![Kepler Pydev config]
I had to spend lot of time to figure out why it is not working. But ultimately did. Download 2.8.2 zip instead and unzip in dropins folder as shown. Start eclipse with -clean option

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment on Tobx's answer so I'll make a new one.

You can install java7 but retain your current version and not affect your current set up by specifying which JVM Eclipse should use using the command line -vm option.

[All is explained here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM)

Answer (score 0):

I debugged a python project (imported before). The Pydev menu has reappeared by only changing the current perspective to "Debug".

I think opening the Pydev perspective through Window > Open Perspective > Other ... > Pydev would also create the Pydev menu.