# PyDev installation problems with Kepler and Mac OS

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I have Eclipse (Kepler) installed on OS X and updated recently to Maverick. Since then I didn't start Eclipse. Yesterday I did and it told me that there are update available. I installed them, with the result that Eclipse didn't remember to have a perspective for PyDev.

I uninstalled PyDev, reinstalled it and since then it doesn't even appear in the preferences. I can uninstall it again, meaning Eclipse knows it is there, but there is simply no way to configure it.

Today I trashed the whole Eclipse, downloaded a fresh one and installed PyDev via the update site... Same story!

Has anybody the same problem on OS X?

Cheers, Tom

Comment: possible duplicate of [PyDev not showing up in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873064/pydev-not-showing-up-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've seen this on Windows 7, after a recent update to Eclipse Kepler and PyDev 3.0.x.  The PyDev site states that the latest PyDev requires Java 7.  If you don't have Java 7, use PyDev 2.  (http://pydev.org/, under the "Release 3.0" title").  I'm using Java 6 to launch Eclipse.

I would check the versions of Java and PyDev you're running.

Comment: I changed my Eclipse configuration to launch with Java 7 and the PyDev perspective appears again.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Gerry!
I installed the recent JDK and updated the symlink for the CurrentJDK. Then I started Eclipse where PyDev was already installed but didn't show up in the preferences, and this time it is there.

Answer (score 5):

Not enough rep to comment on Gerry Kuhn's answer so I'll make a new one.

You can install java7 but retain your current version and not affect your current set up by specifying which JVM Eclipse should use using the command line -vm option.

[All is explained here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM)

Answer (score 3):

Same problem on my Mac here with

> Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 1
>   PyDev 3.0.0.201311051910 org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group

solved by using 2.x version
just download zip [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/pydev/) and extracted folder in the dropin directory and restart is ok now 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the eclipse.ini file.
I changed from this value

-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.**6**

to this value.

-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.**7**

But of course you must have jdk 7 installed previously.