# Python in Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I followed the steps from this video to start using Python in Eclipse
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHRRiBHI3to. I installed the plugins, of course.

Now, the step where I need to navigate windows -> preferences -> pyDev for interpretation, the pyDev box or an option to open that box in the video won't even show. I'm a newbie I just recently started using Eclipse.

Comment: Did you enable yhe python perspective?

Comment: no direct answer, but if you are just looking to work with an IDE there is always pycharm.

Comment: PyCharm is indeed the best IDE for python! ;)

Comment: Odds are it did not install properly, then. Which JRE are you using, which Eclipse version, and did you see any warnings or errors during installation?  Is there anything shown in the Error Log view or the workspace's .metadata\.log file?

Comment: I installed Eclipse itself on Windows using [these instructions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation) in Eclipsepedia, then installed pyDev using the information and links at the end of the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some issue with PyDev 3.0 and the current latest eclipse 4.3.1. Do not know which has the problem. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873064/pydev-not-showing-up-in-eclipse) question and [downloaded 2.8.2 from SF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/pydev/PyDev%202.8.2/PyDev%202.8.2.zip/download) worked for me. So i ened up with eclipse 4.3.1 and PyDev 2.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

(1) You need to switch to the pydev perspective

[image]

(2) Right click your project and create pymodule to start coding.

[image]

(3) Eclipse is really a handy/FREE IDE to work with. I will spend more time figuring it out instead of switching to other options. If you had a really bad luck somehow, try [APTANA](http://www.aptana.com/) instead Pycharm, which is extremely similar like Eclipse but dedicated to Python.

Update:
if you cannot see the Pydev perspective, maybe try to open it in the window drop down list:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but, I don't even have the option to start a new PyDev module OR to add/switch to the pyDev perspective.. PyDev just won't appear for me anywhere.

Comment: @user2980873 Can you take a try to open it in the window drop down list or something similar for windows if you are using a windows box.