# PyDev not showing up in Eclipse 3.8

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-14.04, pydev, ubuntu-16.04

After I installed eclipse 3.8 on Ubuntu 16.04 (same as 14.04), I tried to install PyDev in Help->Install New Software->Add pydev.org/updates.

Everything seems to have gone went well but after restarting eclipse I cannot see PyDev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you already install PyDev 5.xx.. in your eclipse 3.8, uninstall them:

```
help->install new software->click on "already installed" highlight
```

then uninstall PyDev 5.xx...

Now you can install the correct version (4.5.5) of PyDev for eclipse 3.8

```
help->install new software->Add https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/4.5.5/
```

Then go thru the install process and done!

Comment: thanks, this helped, you should consider marking your answer as correct!