# PyDev Not Showing Up in Eclipse 4.19

Tags: python, eclipse, plugins, pydev

I know this has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873064/pydev-not-showing-up-in-eclipse), but I'm still not able to get it to work.

I installed Eclipse 4.19.0 (win-64) and added PyDev 8.3.0.  I have Java 11 installed and Eclipse seems see it:

```
java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11
java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python39\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ravioli\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.
java.runtime.version=11.0.11+9-LTS-194
java.version=11.0.11
java.vm.version=11.0.11+9-LTS-194
org.osgi.framework.system.capabilities=osgi.ee; osgi.ee="OSGi/Minimum"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1, 1.2", osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JRE"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1", osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE/compact1"; version:List<Version>="1.8, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE/compact2"; version:List<Version>="1.8, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE/compact3"; version:List<Version>="1.8, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0"
sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11\bin
```

The PyDev manual says:

```
PyDev requires Java 11 and Eclipse 4.6 (Neon)

If you need to use an older version of Eclipse/Java/Python, below 
is the latest PyDev version to be used based on your requisites.

Eclipse 4.18, Java 8: PyDev 8.2.0
Eclipse 4.5, Java 8: PyDev 5.2.0
...
```

I saw there was a [bug](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pydev-python-ide-eclipse/login-warning) with Eclipse 4.19 and PyDev, but it looks to be resolved.  I can't get PyDev to show up in my Eclipse install.  Any ideas?

Comment: The bug report says it is fixed in Eclipse 4.20 (2021-06 released a few days ago) so try that.

Comment: Oops, I missed the Fix Version.  Thank you kindly, that did the trick.