# PyDev Perspective not showing after Install on Eclipse 3.8

Tags: eclipse, pydev, ubuntu-16.04

Running ubuntu 16.04. Oracle Java 8 installed, OpenJDK uninstalled.

Installed Eclipse 4.2 and PyDev would work OK, but after 2nd start of eclipse, menus won't be clickable anymore.

So I reverted my manual installation of Eclipse 4.2 to Eclipse 3.8, which is available via apt-get install eclipse-platform in the Ubuntu repositories. Installed PyDev via http://pydev.org/updates .

PyDev Perspective won't show up. Trying to re-install PyDev will be blocked by Eclipse because it is already installed.
Trying to click File --> New --> PyDev Project doesn't exist, either.

Already checked [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827404/pydev-not-recognized-in-eclipse?rq=1)

which does not answer my question.

Comment: Are you sure that Eclipse 3.8 is using Java 8? See help > about > installation details > configuration and look for the java.version=xxx entry.

Comment: Hello Fabio, yes it shows:

'java.specification.version=1.8
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vm.info=mixed mode'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked more into this issue and unfortunately, it seems that PyDev really is no longer able to work with Eclipse 3.8. The reason is that Eclipse 3.8 isn't forward-compatible regarding java, so, it doesn't recognize a 'JavaSE-1.8' environment when it's running in Java 8 (and thus, disables PyDev or any plugin which needs Java 8 to run even if Java 8 is required).

This means that the last PyDev version which supports Eclipse 3.8 is PyDev 4.5.5 (so, you have to get that version -- note that you may need to uninstall the 5.x version before -- or you have to update to a newer Eclipse -- i.e.: one that knows how to recognize Java 8).

The update site for PyDev 4.5.5 is http://www.pydev.org/update_sites/4.5.5 -- I'll update the homepage to signal that properly.

Comment: Fabio, thanks for the insight. So we can conclude that there is no way to get PyDev running with standard Eclipse from the Ubuntu repos. Hope that 16.10 will update Eclipse...

Comment: Strange: you mean standard Eclipse is still 3.8? 3.8 is from Jan/2013, so, it's **very** old already (in which case, I think you should not use it anyways... you can download your own from eclipse.org -- or liclipse.com if you want a version with PyDev builtin).